# Foundation Tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having trouble with tabs on foundation 5. It doesn't switch between the 2 tabs and  the css doesn't seem to be working either.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XP6Bk/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
      <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Nutrition Plans</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Fitness Plans</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-7 columns">
        <p class="serv-intro">We can give advice & offer you a personalised nutrition Our nutrition plan will not leave you hungry but it will achieve results so you can look your best.</p>
        <p class="serv-body">One of the key factors of living a healthy lifestyle is having the right nutrition. Making the correct choices and sourcing the correct food has a massive influence on your health &amp; wellbeing.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="large-5 columns">
          <p class="serv-intro">Our Advice will depend on the following:</p>
            <ul class="serv-list">
             <li>Weight</li><hr>
             <li>BMI &amp; Calorie Intake</li><hr>
             <li>Blood Pressure &amp; Heart Rate Checks</li><hr>
             <li>Eating Habits &amp; Lifestyle</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-7 columns">
          <p class="serv-intro">Eating Healthy For Life.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="large-5 columns">
          <p class="serv-intro">Professional Analysts</p>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-7 columns">
            <p class="serv-body">There are many misconceptions about the quality and type of foods that make up a healthy eating plan. Often people under eat which reduces their metabolic rate and lowers the rate you could be increasing your body fat mass. The immediate decrease in weight is often the result of losing lean muscle tissue and dehydration. Losing weight isn’t about eating less. It's important to realise that losing healthily isn’t a quick fix, it's learning to make healthy choices for life.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="large-5 columns">
            <p class="serv-body">We use professional software to analyse and devise your personal nutrition plan based on your specific needs</p>
          </div>
        </div>

  </div>

    <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <p>Hello Dave</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: jquery is missing in your fiddle which causes the first error. You might want to check for other js errors in your browser.

Comment: I've inspected it with chrome and its displaying any errors which is weird @flec

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I downloaded the most recent foundation file and replaced the JS and CSS folders and it now works.